# Perl to JSON, with key/value pairs

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to output some data from Perl to JSON. I can do a simple output, but would like to structure it better.

I have an array with an id, a start time and an end time. This is the code I am using to output:

```
print header('application/json');
my $json->{$entry} = \@array;
my $json_text = to_json($json);
print $json_text;
```

Which returns:

```
{"Season":[["1","1330065300","1344038401"],["7","1298505601","1312416001"]]}
```

But I would like to output something more like:

```
{"Season":0[{"id":1,"DateStart":1330065300,"DateEnd":1344038401},{"id":7,"DateStart":1298505601,"DateEnd":1312416001}]}
```

Can anyone help on how to better structure my output?

---UPDATE------

Thanks Michael. I have tried to implement your example.

This is the code at the moment:

```
foreach my $key (keys %$seasons)
    {
        $seasons->{$key} =
        [
            map
            {
                { id=>$_[0], DateStart=>$_[1], DateEnd=>$_[2] }
            } @{$seasons->{$key}}
        ];
    }
```

But it returns the error (referring to the foreach line):

```
Not a HASH reference at line 148
```

$seasons is an arrayref return from a SQL fetchall_arrayref

Any clues?

Comment: Are you able to use CPAN libraries like http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-2.32/XS.pm?

Comment: The code you say you want to return is invalid JSON. Should that `0` really be there?

Comment: If you want a hash in JSON, that part of the structure has to be a hash in the Perl structure.

Comment: The error message pretty much explains it -- a hash reference is expected, while you're passing an array reference. Try replacing the `foreach` line with `foreach my $key (keys @$seasons)`, and both occurrences of `$seasons->{$key}` with `$seasons->[$key]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to convert an array of arrays to an array of hashes, and you can do this using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). Assuming `$data` is your structure, this should do it:

```
for my $key (keys %$data) {
    $data->{$key} = [
        map {
            { id => $_->[0], DateStart => $_->[1], DateEnd => $_->[2] }
        } @{$data->{$key}}
    ];      
}
```

Comment: Hey Michael, could you please check my updated code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output an array of objects with key/value pairs instead of an array of arrays, then put appropriate data into `to_json` in the first place.

i.e. an array of hashrefs and not an array of arrayrefs.

You can [use `map` to transform the data](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're trying something like this, always check CPAN to see if someone has done it before and not try to reinvent the wheel. I found a module called [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm) that seems to do exactly what you want.

There's an example on that page that does exactly what you want. Here's a quick paraphrase:

```
use JSON; # imports encode_json, decode_json, to_json and from_json.

# simple and fast interfaces (expect/generate UTF-8)
my $utf8_encoded_json_text = encode_json \@array;
```

Can't get easier than that. The best part is that this will work no matter how complex your array structure gets.

Comment: Apparently, the asker is already using the JSON module. There's a call to `to_json` in the code.